# Changing path of pip to Virtual Env

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I've cloned a codebase from Heroku onto a new comp, when I try to run it none of the Python libraries that I've installed are present. After I run `which pip` I see that my path is `/usr/local/bin/pip`.
(1) How do I change the path so all the libraries install into  my virtual env and (2) how can I install everything from my `requirements.txt` instead of individually install libraries.

```
(venv)admins-MacBook-Air:lhv-talenttracker surajkapoor$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: When dealing with a virtual env usually once you activate that environment anything you pip will get installed in that virtual env

Comment: @user2097159 that's not happening. I'm activating the environment and then running pip install

Comment: After activating the environment and you do a which pip does it still give the same location?

Comment: @user2097159 yup, same location

Comment: Try looking at your `venv/bin/activate` file and see if the `VIRTUAL_ENV` matches your current path.

Comment: Thanks @Anzel, that was the issue. My file name was incorrect

Comment: @SurajKapoor, yeah it happens sometimes especially when we get the source from other repository, or copying to other computers. Please report if this solves your issue and accept my answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at your `venv/bin/activate` file and see if the `VIRTUAL_ENV` matches your current path. If it doesn't match, change it to match your path and activate again.

```
$ cat activate |grep VIRTUAL_ENV=

VIRTUAL_ENV="/does/this/path/match?"
```