# pip installing in global not in my local virtualenv even I'm in venv though

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

```
(venv) C:\Users\me\Desktop\Just Do It\Project\my_project>
```

I'm in my virtualenv right?

But when  I hit `pip list` It show me all the global package in my machine

```
(venv) C:\Users\me\Desktop\Just Do It\Project\my_project>pip list
```

There should be only one package in `venv` Django that I have install recently!
Need help!

Comment: Have tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805896/changing-path-of-pip-to-virtual-env which is to look at the `activate` script you are using to make sure it point to the right folder?

Answer (score 0):

Funny my problem solved by not putting venv in my project folder.

I mean activate the venv first and navigate project folder and you are good to go!
:/

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```py
pip list --user

pip install <package> --user
```

Comment: Nope not working!

Comment: Windows can be a funny beast with this stuff. Try pip3?